# Count number of quotes in a file using Scala in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am using Spark and Scala as language. I am trying to read a file and count the number of spaces and quotes in it. I am getting the correct output for space but incorrect for number of quotes in the file. Is the expression correct?

```
val file = sc.textFile("file:///Users/Desktop/test/employee.txt")
1) val space = file.filter(line => line.contains(" ")).count() --O/P = 2
2) val counter = file.filter(line => line.contains('"')).count() - Wrong Output

      File :
     "abc","def","xyc","asas", "esd"
      "343","32","234","11", "RE"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like both expressions are incorrect. If I'm getting you right, you want to all spaces and quotes but your code calculates count of lines having spaces/quotes.

One more issue: use '\"' instead of '"'

Fix:

```
val space = file.map(line => line.count(_==' ')).sum()
val counter = file.map(line => line.count(_=='\"')).sum()
```